# have "git show" use opendiff on osx to show commits

Tags: git, git-show, opendiff

I found ways to use opendiff for "git diff" but "git show" doesn't have quite the same options.

Comment: I think `git show` is more like `git log` and not really like `git diff` even though `git show` does sometimes show diffs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, `git-show` runs `git diff-tree -cc` behind the scenes to produce the diff output. This probably bypasses your `git-diff` customizations.

Try changing your .gitconfig to add the same options when you run `git-diff` as `git-diff-tree`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convince git diff to show you the difference between the last two commits using this bit of a hack:

```
COMMITS=$(git log --name-status HEAD^^..HEAD | grep "commit" | sed 's/commit/ /')
COMMITS=($COMMITS)
git diff ${COMMITS[1]} ${COMMITS[0]}
```

in which case git will use whatever editor you told it to use for git diff.